# DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body 2.options[2].choices: Choices cannot be configured for this type of option

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I had just finished coding the ban command, and when I wanted to run the bot, I got a giant error. I never even had an idea what this error means, so if you could explain it to me while looking for the fix would be appreciated. If you can't, that's also okay.

```
DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
2.options[2].choices: Choices cannot be configured for this type of option
```

I looked for the issue, but I can't seem to find any. Can someone help me with this one?

Here is the code:

```js
const { Client, CommandInteraction, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'ban',
    description: 'Bans the target member',
    permission: 'ADMINISTRATOR',
    options: [{
            name: 'target',
            description: 'Select a target to ban.',
            type: 'USER',
            required: true,
        },
        {
            name: 'reason',
            description: 'Provide a reason for this ban.',
            type: 'STRING',
            required: true,
        },
        {
            name: 'messages',
            description: 'Choose one of the choices.',
            type: 'USER',
            required: true,
            choices: [{
                    name: 'Don\'t delete any',
                    value: '0'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Previous 7 days.',
                    value: '7'
                }
            ]
        },
    ],
    /**
     * 
     * @param {Client} client 
     * @param {CommandInteraction} interaction 
     */
    async execute(client, interaction) {
        const { options, member } = interaction;

        const Target = options.getMember('target');

        if (Target.id === member.id)
            return interaction.reply({
                embeds: [new MessageEmbed().setColor('RED').setDescription(`⛔ | You can't ban yourself.`)]
            })

        if (Target.permissions.has('ADMINISTRATOR'))
            return interaction.reply({
                embeds: [new MessageEmbed().setColor('RED').setDescription(`⛔ | You can't an administrator.`)]
            })

        const Reason = options.getString('reason');

        if (Reason.length > 512)
            return interaction.reply({
                embeds: [new MessageEmbed().setColor('RED').setDescription(`⛔ | The reason can't exceed 512 characters.`)]
            })

        const Amount = options.getString('messages')

        Target.ban({
            days: Amount,
            reason: Reason
        })

        interaction.reply({
            embeds: [new MessageEmbed().setColor('GREEN').setDescription(`✅ | **${target.user.username}** has been banned from the server.`)]
        })
    }
};
```

Comment: Well, you can't add choices to `type: "USER"`

Comment: If my answer worked, make sure to mark it as the best answer! You can also upvote if you are not the owner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `USER` type can't have choices. It looks like you need `STRING` instead. For example, your code would look like this:

```js
const { Client, CommandInteraction, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'ban',
    description: 'Bans the target member',
    permission: 'ADMINISTRATOR',
    options: [{
            name: 'target',
            description: 'Select a target to ban.',
            type: 'USER',
            required: true,
        },
        {
            name: 'reason',
            description: 'Provide a reason for this ban.',
            type: 'STRING',
            required: true,
        },
        {
            name: 'messages',
            description: 'Choose one of the choices.',
            type: 'STRING',
            required: true,
            choices: [{
                    name: 'Don\'t delete any',
                    value: '0'
                },
                {
                    name: 'Previous 7 days.',
                    value: '7'
                }
            ]
        },
    ],
    /**
     * 
     * @param {Client} client 
     * @param {CommandInteraction} interaction 
     */
    async execute(client, interaction) {
        const { options, member } = interaction;

        const Target = options.getMember('target');

        if (Target.id === member.id)
            return interaction.reply({
                embeds: [new MessageEmbed().setColor('RED').setDescription(`⛔ | You can't ban yourself.`)]
            })

        if (Target.permissions.has('ADMINISTRATOR'))
            return interaction.reply({
                embeds: [new MessageEmbed().setColor('RED').setDescription(`⛔ | You can't an administrator.`)]
            })

        const Reason = options.getString('reason');

        if (Reason.length > 512)
            return interaction.reply({
                embeds: [new MessageEmbed().setColor('RED').setDescription(`⛔ | The reason can't exceed 512 characters.`)]
            })

        const Amount = options.getString('messages')

        Target.ban({
            days: Amount,
            reason: Reason
        })

        interaction.reply({
            embeds: [new MessageEmbed().setColor('GREEN').setDescription(`✅ | **${target.user.username}** has been banned from the server.`)]
        })
    }
};
```

See [here](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/registering-slash-commands.html#choices) for the reference.

**Hoped this helped!**